# How come revents is 0 when the cable is unplugged?

Tags: c, linux, networking

I have a function to check the ethernet link status. When the cable is plugged in, then revents is POLLIN. So the line "Status is changed." is printed out. But if the cable is unplugged, the revents is 0. Then the "Status is changed." isn't printed out. Why revents is 0 when the cable is unplugged? In this case, how can I know if the cable is unplugged?

```
void pollLink()
{
    struct pollfd poll_data[1];
    
    poll_data[0].fd = 0;
    poll_data[0].events = POLLIN;

    poll(poll_data, 1, 0);
    if (poll_data[0].revents == POLLIN)
    {
        printf("Status is changed.");
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Why revents is 0 when the cable is unplugged?"* `POLLIN` means that data may be read without blocking. If the cable is unplugged, there won't be any data to read.

Comment: You might be able to tell that the cable is unplugged by looking at the `POLLHUP` bit in `revents`.

Comment: I checked. The revents is 0 when the cable is unplugged. The POLLUP(0x10) bit is always 0.